# How can I call a class variable instead of the child variable with the same name?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass, init

As always, I start by saying I'm not an expert or professional in any sense, so please judge me tender. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution to this problem, but I'm sure this is not the first time it has appeared here. Therefore, I would appreciate it if you referred me to the relevant thread.

I have a 12 story structure of classes and subclasses. Something like:

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
#class M,N,O(A)....
class C(B):
    pass
```

and so on.

Each class and subclass may have or not have (usually they do have) a property (memory['prop']). and every **init** of any object refers to its super class.

```
class A:
    memory={'prop':{'a':0,'b':1}}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
       for k in kwargs|self.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(kwargs|self.memory['prop'])[k])
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for k in self.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(self.memory['prop'])[k])
class C(B):
    memory={'prop':{'c':2,'d':3}}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for k in self.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(self.memory['prop'])[k])
```

The problem here is that, if I create a C object, it will call C.memory['prop'] every time the algorithm calls the variable within an **init** function. What I need is to call the 'current' class memory.

In the example, if I run `object=C(**{'e'=4})`, I will get an object with attributes `'c'`, `'d'` and `'e'`, but not `'a'` or `'b'`.

I know I can do this by using:

```
class A:
    memory={'prop':{'a':0,'b':1}}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
       for k in kwargs|A.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(kwargs|A.memory['prop'])[k])
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for k in B.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(B.memory['prop'])[k])
class C(B):
    memory={'prop':{'c':2,'d':3}}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for k in C.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(C.memory['prop'])[k])
```

But this means I have to do an extra job everytime I define a class (there's about a thousand of them)

I can also do something like this:

```
class A:
    memory={'prop':{'a':0,'b':1}}
    def __init__(self,clas,**kwargs):
       for k in kwargs|clas.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(kwargs|clas.memory['prop'])[k])
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,clas,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(clas,**kwargs)
        for k in clas.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(clas.memory['prop'])[k])
class C(B):
    memory={'prop':{'c':2,'d':3}}
    def __init__(self,clas,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(clas,**kwargs)
        for k in clas.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(clas.memory['prop'])[k])
```

But this means I have to call the same class everytime I create an object `object=C(C)` which looks wrong.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can refer to the variables as `A.memory`, `B.memory`, etc.

Comment: What's the point of using the same variable name if you don't want the subclass to override it?

Comment: "I have a 12 story structure of classes and subclasses" sounds like a misdesign to begin with... What is it that you're really aiming for?

Comment: @AKX Why? I'm modeling something like a taxonomy, would it be wrong to built an 8 story structure if I were classifying living beings?

Comment: @AKX. Agreed. There is a lot of code smell here. Doing `(kwargs|clas.memory['prop'])[k]` in a loop is really bothering me.

Comment: @Barmar Because it would be harder to get a different name for each one...

Comment: @MadPhysicist that one is only in the upper parent class, which prevents kwargs from being called more than once, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @JoséChamorro. You could initialize `x = kwargs|clas.memory['prop']` one time outside the loop. You do realize that every time you use that operator, you're recomputing the entire temp dictionary?

Comment: Is your intent to override `kwargs` with the default values?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh I'm sorry, that was just a mistake when coping the code to the question. Look at it now. kwargs is only used by the init function of class A, which is the 'upper' parent class. Any other sub-class only uses its own memory. I got my answer, btw. I have to call ____class____.memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `prop` to be a class attribute, but need a fresh instance of it for each subclass.

An easy thing to do is to create a `prop`in the `__init_subclass__` method: this is a reserved method the language calls each time a subclass is created:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class A:
    memory={'prop':{'a':0,'b':1}}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
       cls = type(self) # it is better to be specific that we want to update a class property
       for k in kwargs|self.memory['prop']:
            if k not in self.__dict__:
                setattr(self,k,(kwargs|cls.memory['prop'])[k])

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw)
        # this will create a copy of A.memory for each subclass.
        # (__class__ is a special value that always points to THIS (A)
        # class, while "cls", received as a parameter, refers to the
        # subclass that is being created: 
        cls.memory = deepcopy(__class__.memory)
        # if you prefer each subclass to start with an empty memory:
        # cls.memory = {}

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # no need for any other code in the subclasses __init__ - 
        # the code on the superclass will store it on the apropriate 
        # dictionary for each class
```

Comment: You're making a shallow copy...

Comment: Indeed. as the OP was interested in a nested dictionary of "memory", it would be of no use. Fixed now

Comment: I like your shorter solution.

Comment: This code provided the solution to my question so I accepted it as the correct answer. The code doesn't work, but the use of both __init_subclass__ and __class__ are clear

Comment: the code should work. In the first draft I was using "copy"instead of deepcopy: it would not work on your particular dictionary because the keys of interest are deeply nested.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be very excited to abuse the new dictionary union operator. Not only are you running it repeatedly in a loop every time you want to access a key, but it's obscuring your actual design, which is likely flawed:

1. Apply `kwargs`
2. Override them with class level defaults

Remember that that the union operator is non-commutative for dictionaries: the last right hand operator's value is always used in case of conflict. This is backwards from how such things are normally done (what's the point of `kwargs` at that point?), but let's ignore that for a minute.

You seem to want classes along your inheritance chain to be able to update `__dict__` in `__init__`. That is fundamentally the opposite of inheritance, which hides the parent attribute. You can absorb the dictionary update into a method calls, which can use `super` to make sure the entire chain is handled:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(self.get_defaults())
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

     @classmethod
     def set_defaults(cls):
         return {'A': 1, 'B': 2}

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    @classmethod
    def get_defaults(cls):
        return super().get_defaults() | {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

This way, you only ever need a single constructor. It also has the potential advantage of allowing you to generate the default values on the fly.